# git-svn commits to wrong branch / how to merge svn branch via git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, branching-and-merging

I have a SVN repository which I checked out with git-svn, using the `--stdlayout` option (at that time, the repo was empty).

I then worked on the master branch for a while. When using `git svn dcommit`, it would svn-commit my changes to `https://my.host/repo/trunk` like it should.

At some point I created a branch named "arithmetics" with git. Later I wanted to create that branch in svn too, so I did a `git svn branch arithmetics` and then a `git branch --set-upstream arithmetics remotes/arithmetics` as suggested by a website. I suppose this is where things went wrong, as I got a warning about `--set-upstream` being deprecated.

When calling `git svn dcommit`, it would commit to `https://my.host/repo/branches/arithmetics`, so far so good. But then I noticed, that `dcommit` would commit to that branch regardless of the currently checked out branch in the git repository, when I tried merging the branch back into master.

I even tried creating a new clone from svn, merging the branch into master there. I also tried checking out `trunk` explicitly with `git checkout -b local/trunk remotes/trunk`, then merging the branch into that and then `git svn dcommit`. It would always commit to the branch again.

How can I fix this?

PS: I used `git rebase` for merging, as I read, that merge-commits were problematic with git-svn, so I don't have any of those.

Comment: It's easy to understand where git-svn dcommit will send changes: run "git log" and look at "git-svn-id:" signature. There will be the URL to send the changes to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dcommit *git branches* to an SVN repository, because Git and SVN have totally different notions of branches. Merging with git and then calling dcommit will linearize your history (quite the same as with rebase) and then push to the currently checked out branch.

Here's the important part from the manpage of [`git svn`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html):

> [**MERGE TRACKING**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_merge_tracking)
>      While git svn can track copy history (including branches and tags) for
>      repositories adopting a standard layout, it cannot yet represent merge
>      history that happened inside git back upstream to SVN users. Therefore
>      it is advised that users keep history as linear as possible inside git
>      to ease compatibility with SVN (see the CAVEATS section below).

Also, the [**caveats**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_caveats) section has a paragraph dedicated to your problem:

> Running git merge or git pull is NOT recommended on a branch you plan
>   to dcommit from because Subversion users cannot see any merges you’ve
>   made. Furthermore, if you merge or pull from a git branch that is a
>   mirror of an SVN branch, dcommit may commit to the wrong branch.
>
> If you do merge, note the following rule: git svn dcommit will attempt
>   to commit on top of the SVN commit named in
>
> ```
> git log --grep=^git-svn-id: --first-parent -1
> ```

Comment: does that mean, I cannot merge my SVN branch from git anymore, because the commits in it have been commited to svn? or can I change the git-svn-id for a commit?

Comment: I guess if you want to use Git for merging SVN branches, you'd have to do a --squash merge and then manually set the merge-properties (this step is optional). I don't know if your particular commits are already in the SVN repository – you're the only one who can find out (svn log, git log, git svn log, …)